# How to find boundary for set of points in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set of XYZ coordinates (lake bathymetry) and I want to create a grid out of them for later meshing purposes using GMSH. I know that there is an easy way to do it in MATLAB using the boundary(x,y,z) function. Unfortunately, I couln't find anything similar in R and I have too many points to create boundary lines by hand.

Does anyone has an idea how to proceed with this in R? At the end I need the lines consisting of the outer points in my point cloud.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `chull` which finds the convex hull.
From the chull help

```
X <- matrix(stats::rnorm(2000), ncol = 2)
chull(X)


plot(X[,1],X[,2])
points(X[chull(X),1],X[chull(X),2],col=2,pch=19)
```

Comment: thanks, I used chull now (after learning that there is a lot about convex hull algorithms) but at the end I only get the coarse boundary. My point data cloud is really diverse like sitting in a W form. What I really need would be the location of the edge points to get a tigh line around all points.So a boundary line which follows the distribution of all my points instead of the rough boundary around all points